# CSS flip animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, css-transforms

I have a simple HTML form asking for general information with a button at the bottom labeled "next". Once I button is pressed, I have jQuery triggered to cause a "card flip" animation. What I would like to do is to reveal additional questions on the "back" side of the flip, containing a "Submit" button at the bottom of the back side. I need a way to create a blank page on the back side, so I can enter additional input fields.

What would be the easiest way to remove the input fields on the front side of the form, so I can create additional questions on the back side of the form?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='next']").on("click", function() {
    // console.log( "The Button Worked!" );
    $(".form").css("transform", "rotateY(180deg)");
  })
});
```

```css
/*CSS FOR MY FORM*/

.form {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: space-between;
}
.formTitle {
  border-bottom: solid red;
}
.form-style-5 {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  max-width: 60%;
  max-height: 82vh;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f4f7f8;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}
#form-style-5-Animation {
  animation: slide 3s 1;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 1000%, 0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px);
  }
}
.form-style-5:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-style-5 fieldset {
  border: none;
}
.form-style-5 legend {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-style-5 label {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="text"],
.form-style-5 input[type="date"],
.form-style-5 input[type="datetime"],
.form-style-5 input[type="email"],
.form-style-5 input[type="location"],
.form-style-5 input[type="number"],
.form-style-5 input[type="search"],
.form-style-5 input[type="time"],
.form-style-5 input[type="url"],
.form-style-5 textarea,
.form-style-5 select {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding-left: 2%;
  height: 6%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #e8eeef;
  color: #8a97a0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="text"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="date"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="datetime"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="email"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="number"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="search"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="time"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="location"]:focus,
.form-style-5 textarea:focus,
.form-style-5 select:focus {
  background: #d2d9dd;
}
.form-style-5 select {
  -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
  height: 35px;
}
.form-style-5 .number {
  background: red;
  color: #FCFBE3;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 4px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="submit"],
.form-style-5 input[type="button"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 39px 10px 39px;
  color: #FCFBE3;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #b30000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="submit"]:active,
.form-style-5 input[type="button"]:active {
  transform: translateY(3px);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #b30000;
}
.form-style-5 input[type="submit"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="button"]:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.next {
  -webkit-transition-duration: .01s;
  -moz-transition-duration: .01s;
  -o-transition-duration: .01s;
  transition-duration: .01s;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
}
/*THE REST OF MY CSS*/

body,
div,
h1,
h1,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
ul,
ol,
li,
dl,
dt,
dd,
img,
form {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 55px;
  width: 162px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 222;
  opacity: 1;
}
header {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: .8;
}
.banner {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: .8;
}
#banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  background: url("banner.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 100%;
  text-shadow: 20px black;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}
.button1,
.button2,
.button3,
.button4 {
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 120px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  float: right;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 1.5px;
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.button1:hover,
.button2:hover,
.button3:hover,
.button4:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.button1:focus,
.button2:focus,
.button3:focus,
.button4:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
#formOpacity {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="banner">
    <div class="banner"></div>
    <div class="form-style-5" id="form-style-5-Animation">
      <div class="form">
        <form action="send-sms.php" method="POST">
          <fieldset class='flex'>
            <legend>
              <div class="formTitle">Fill out the form below to request help!</div>
            </legend>
            <input type="text" name="field1" id="name" placeholder="Your Name *">
            <input type="text" name="field3" id="location" placeholder="Your Location (i.e. McNutt, exact address, etc.)*">
            <input type="text" name="field4" id="misc" placeholder="Miscellaneous Information That May Be Important">
            <input type="email" name="field2" id="email" placeholder="Email Address"><span class="number">or</span>
            </h4>
            <input type="text" name="field5" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
            <input type="text" id="task" name="field6" placeholder="Task that needs completion, let us know how we can help!*"></input>
          </fieldset>
          <input name="next" type="button" value="Next" class="next" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `backface-visibility`?

Comment: already found [davidwalsh.name/css-flip](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip)?

Comment: You shouldn't need to remove any data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could have two `<div>`s, one with the id of `#front-side` and the other with `#back-side`. When you click the card, it sets `#front-side` to `display: none;` and `#back-side` to `display: block;` and vice versa.

So for your code, if I am reading it right:

```
<div class="form">
  <div id="front-side">      
    <form action="send-sms.php" method="POST">
      <fieldset class='flex'>
        <legend>
          <div class="formTitle">
            Fill out the form below to request help!
          </div>
        </legend>
        <input type="text" name="field1" id="name" placeholder="Your Name *">
        <input type="text" name="field3" id="location" placeholder="Your Location">
        <input type="text" name="field4" id="misc" placeholder="Miscellaneous Information That May Be Important">
        <input type="email" name="field2" id="email" placeholder="Email Address"><span class="number">or</span>
        </h4>
        <input type="text" name="field5" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
        <input type="text" id="task" name="field6" placeholder="Task that needs completion, let us know how we can help!*"></input>
      </fieldset>
      <input name="next" type="button" value="Next" class="next" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="back-side">
    <span>back-side stuff here</span>
  </div>
</div>
```